# Invoke default case in switch c#

Tags: c#, enums

For example let i have something like this.

```
public enum CarEnum { BWM, LadaKalina };

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var carEnum = CarEnum.LadaKalina;
            GetMessage(carEnum);
        }
        public static void GetMessage(CarEnum carEnum)
        {
            switch (carEnum)
            {
                case CarEnum.BWM:
                    Console.WriteLine("BWM");
                    break;
                case CarEnum.LadaKalina:
                    Console.WriteLine("LadaKalina");
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("default");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to Invoke default case in function GetMessage. What it's better to pass like argument?

Comment: Not sure I understand. To hit the default you'd just pass something other than BWM and LadaKalina.

Comment: does `GetMessage((CarEnum)-1);` count?

Comment: Add a `None = 0` member to the enum, pass that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd provide an enum value that can be used as default/unknown:

```
public enum CarEnum { Unknown, BWM, LadaKalina };

GetMessage(CarEnum.Unknown);
```

Comment: but if Unknown already exist in enum and using for other reasons? Then only magic numbers?

Comment: @A191919 then... maybe `Nullable<CarEnum>` aka `CarEnum?` ?

Comment: Or just pick a name that is not in use.  *None* is recommended by Code Analysys rules.

Answer (score 4):

It's a common convention to add a `None` enum value to indicate none of the values in the enum:

```
public enum CarEnum { None, BWM, LadaKalina };
```

And use it like:

```
GetMessage(CarEnum.None);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
GetMessage((CarEnum)-1);
```

EDIT:

Base on Marc Gravell's comment on other answer I've tested and you could use

```
        CarEnum? car = null;

        switch (car)
        {
            case CarEnum.BWM:
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Default");
                break;
        }
```